# Import C++ code to IOS application

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I write a code in C++, and I want to use some of it's methods in my IOS application, so is it possible to (import)  C++ library "t.cpp" to IOS application in XCode?
if yes what's the simple way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that will work without error, however you might want to change the Xcode C++ compiler settings (language level and runtime library), depending on the version of iOS you are using.

When it comes to actually using the C++ classes within your Objective-C code, you simply need to rename any files from `.m` to `.mm`.

A complication occurs when you want to include the C++ headers in Objective-C headers where both `.m` and `.mm` see that Objective-C header file.  In this case you might find that you need to change many more files from `.m` to `.mm` in order for this to work, but there are ways around this if that becomes too onerous.

Comment: To avoid the issue of exposing C++ headers to too many other files, I like to write Objective-C classes that wrap corresponding C++ classes or functionality. Then, ideally the C++ headers are only included from the wrapper `.mm` file, and the `.h` file for the Objective-C wrapper class has a nice clean interface with no hint of C++.

Comment: @esker Sounds like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the file to the project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename a file from .m too .mm only if the [translation unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) contains a C++ header. Then, the module gets "infected" by C++ and needs to be compiled with the Objective-C++ compiler.

This is only required if any C++ header will be directly or indirectly included/imported from that module. There is no need to rename *all* files.

Additionally, if this C++ code depends on the C++ standard lib, you need also ensure, that the executable binary links against the C++ standard lib, via setting the appropriate build setting in the executable binary.

For example, in the target build settings of your app, add the following option to **Other Linker Flags**:
    `-lc++`
    e.g.:
    `OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC -lc++`

**Caution:**

If possible, don't include/import a C++ header in a *public* Objective-C header, since then all modules will be infected by C++ when they import this Objective-C header and become Objective-C++.